# ugly line appear when I add border to a outer div

Tags: css, border

```css
div {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

#a {
    position: fixed;
    border: 4px solid black;
    background-color:aqua;
}

#b {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div id=a>
    <div id=b></div>
</div>
```

https://www.hualigs.cn/image/60c949e478467.jpg

change a's border to "5px solid black"

https://www.hualigs.cn/image/60c949e425294.jpg

change a's border to "6px solid black"

https://www.hualigs.cn/image/60c949e426a74.jpg

change a's border to "7px solid black"

https://www.hualigs.cn/image/60c949e47c2e2.jpg

What!!! Why!!!  Who can explain？ the broswer is chrome stable version.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is simply a browser rendering issue between the border and the div (I only see this issue on chrome, its not there in firefox).  But you can get rid of that issue by adding this `outline: 1px solid black;` to `#b` in CSS.